# VB.Net - UserControl don't update Controls inside

Tags: vb.net, properties, user-controls, refresh

I'm working on a VB.Net application. I need to create an UserControl I've named signalIO, with a TextBox and a Label, with some properties to change contents of TextBox and Label, change BackColor, etc.

When I add signalIO into the Form of my application, the signalIO control works fine. If I change the parameter StatusSignal from False to True, I can see the backcolor of textbox into control changed from Red to Green, if I change the name of the Signal, I can see text into Label changed correctly.

But if I run on debug the application, I cannot see the changes after the Set methods of the properties.

This is the code I've used:

```
Imports System.ComponentModel
Imports System.Drawing
Imports System.Drawing.Drawing2D
Imports System.ComponentModel.Design
Imports System.Windows.Forms

<Designer("System.Windows.Forms.Design.ParentControlDesigner,System.Design", GetType(IDesigner))> _
Public Class controlIO
    Inherits UserControl

    Private status As Boolean
    Private ID As Integer = 0
    Private label As String

    Public Property labelSignal As String
        Get
            Return labelIO.Text
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            label = value
            labelIO.Text = label
            updateControl()
            Invalidate()
        End Set
    End Property

    Private Sub updateControl()
        Me.Refresh()
        boxIO.Refresh()
        labelIO.Refresh()
    End Sub

    Public Property statusSignal As Boolean
        Get
            Return status
        End Get
        Set(value As Boolean)
            status = value
            If status Then boxIO.BackColor = Color.Green Else boxIO.BackColor = Color.Red
            updateControl()
            Invalidate()
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Property signalIO As Integer
        Get
            Return ID
        End Get
        Set(value As Integer)
            ID = value
            boxIO.Text = CStr(ID)
            updateControl()
            Invalidate()
        End Set
    End Property

End Class
```

I cannot understand why if I change the property statusSignal, for example, I can see the change of the color of boxIO into FormDesigner of the application, but this not changed during execution of the application.

I wish you can understand my question.

Comment: Can you show how you set statusSignal in code

Comment: Considering the name of the control into the application is: "OUT_ELV", I will use this : 
    OUT_ELV.statusSignal = True
That's it!

Comment: Cannot repro - but that is an oddly constructed UserControl.  Usually the INHERITS part is in the partial class of designer generated boilerplate code.  If you created a standard class rather than an actual UserControl, it might be missing stuff.